# When is IOSurfaceLock necessary for IOSurface operations?

Tags: ios, objective-c

To use a fast screen shot, I need to do some IOSurfaceRef operations-- capture image with `CARenderServerRenderDisplay(0, CFSTR("LCD"), iosurfaceref, 0, 0)`, and then convert iosurfaceref to CGImage.
My question is, when and where do I need to put `IOSurfaceLock(surface, 0, nil)` and `IOSurfaceUnlock(surface, 0, 0)` around these IOSurface operations?
This sample code （from https://github.com/k06a/UIView-FastScreenshot/blob/master/UIView%2BFastScreenshot.m） below do everything in the main thread, but still applies IOSurfaceLock， why？

```
IOSurfaceLock(surface, 0, nil);
CARenderServerRenderDisplay(0, CFSTR("LCD"), surface, 0, 0);
void * baseAddr = IOSurfaceGetBaseAddress(surface);
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:baseAddr length:totalBytes];
IOSurfaceUnlock(surface, 0, 0);
```

Comment: any news about this issue

Answer (score 2):

An IOSurface can be shared across multiple processes. On OS X, you can use `IOSurfaceCreateMachPort` or `IOSurfaceCreateXPCObject` to wrap the surface reference in an object that you can send across the process boundary.

Even if **you** only access the surface from your main thread, other processes may also try to use the surface at the same time.

If you're copying data out of the surface while another process is modifying the data in the surface, you won't get a consistent view of the contents of the surface, and vice versa.  To avoid this problem, every process should call `IOSurfaceLock` before reading or writing the surface data, and call `IOSurfaceUnlock` after.

Comment: On iOS 12-13 `ReplayKit2` in sample handlers `IOSurfaceLock`/`IOSurfaceUnlock` pairs and comparing before and after `seed` IDs don't seem to be enough to detect and avoid inconsistent `IOSurface`s.